# pptm file not downloading on IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have uploaded a .pptm file on windows 2003 server in a website directory folder. I get a link to the file like www.domainname/media/CLT/ResourceUploads/4021161/proposal%20sample.pptm when I type in the link in the browser address bar I get this error

Gateway Timeout Server error - server xx.xxx.xxxx.176 is unreachable at this moment. Please retry the request or contact your adminstrator.

If I change the extension of the same file to .ppt or .pptx then the document downloads fine.

I have also tried a different sample file (available on this link http://greenvsa.wikispaces.com/file/detail/proposal+sample.pptm) but the result is still the same.

Any ideas or any direction I shall look into? thanks

Comment: Have you added the correct MIME types in IIS? http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: The MIME type was already there on IIS level. Though it was slightly different then I had set with in the code. On IIS I have changed it to "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" to "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.macroEnabled.12" and then added the same to the website directory but the error is still the same